# implementing a interface to a class: class to interface to interface

Tags: java, interface

hi im a beginner in this and im trying to implement a class to a interface. The interface extends another interface. Im making a class with methods to run through a list and interfer with it, the two interfaces are apart of this.

The two interfaces are in each its separate file, but everything is in the same package, hope this is right.

Im getting the following errors:

From the class doublelinkedlist: `interface expected here`

From the interface A: `doublelinkedlist.A is already defined in doublelinkedlist, interface expected here`

From interface B: `doublelinkedlist.B is already defined in doublelinkedlist`

Code class:

```
package doublelinkedlist;

import java.util.*;

public class Doublelinkedlist<T> implements A<T>
{
```

Code interface A: (in separate file called A.java )

```
package doublelinkedlist;

import java.util.Iterator;


public class A<T> { // am I supposed to have a class here? or just have the interface?

  public interface A<T> extends B<T> 
  {
```

Code interface B: (in separate file called B.java )

```
package doublelinkedlist;

public class B<T> {

  public interface B<T> extends Iterable<T> 
  {
```

There is no code for the two interfaces in the class, so I dont understand why i get an error saying its already defined. Anybody got a clue?

Comment: An interface cannot extend from a class, just from another interfaces. A class cannot extend from an interface, just from one single non-final class. A class can implement one or several interfaces.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel you can declare inner interfaces/classes inside a class, there's nothing wrong about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`interface expected here` indicates that the compiler is expecting an interface after `implements`, where you have given it a class (since the declaration for `class A<T>` came first).

`doublelinkedlist.A is already defined in doublelinkedlist, interface expected here` is thrown because you have a class named A and an interface inside the class named A, they can't both have the same name (same with B)

While you can technically have an interface inside of a class, that's not really the best design (since interfaces were intended to abstract, or hide, away the details of the underlying classes, they are typically more visible), so try to avoid doing that unless you have a good reason :)

This is probably what you're looking for:

Doublelinkedlist.java:

```
package doublelinkedlist;

import java.util.*;

public class Doublelinkedlist<T> implements A<T>
{...}
```

A.java:

```
package doublelinkedlist;

import java.util.Iterator;

public interface A<T> extends B<T> 
{...}
```

B.java:

```
package doublelinkedlist;

public interface B<T> extends Iterable<T> 
{...}
```

Further reading on interfaces:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A<T> { // am I supposed to have a class here? or just have the interface?

public interface A<T> extends B<T> 
{
```

This is ambigous. Is A the interface or the class?

Only interfaces can be "implemented". You cannot implement a class.

So I guess your issue is done by changing those into:

File DoubleLinkedList.java:

```
public class Doublelinkedlist<T> implements A<T>
{
 // ... blah blah
}
```

-> The **class** implements interface A

File A.java:

```
public interface A<T> extends B<T> 
{
   // ...
}
```

-> The interface extends interface B

File B.java:

```
public interface B<T> extends Iterable<T> 
{
   // ...
}
```

-> The interface extends interface Iterable

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Entity{

public int getId();
public void setId(int id);
public int getHealth();
public void setHealth(int health);
}

public class Tank implements Entity{

//without implementing the methods mentioned in Entity you will immediately see a red line //under "Tank" in your IDE saying un-implemented methods. 
}
public class Tank implements Entity{
private int id;
private int health;

public Tank(){..}
public int getId(){
return id;
}
public void setId(int id){
this.id = id;
}
public int getHealth(){
return health;
}
public void setHealth(int health){
this.health = health;
}
}
```

an interface is a contract between the class that is implementing the interface, it is saying "HEY YOU, you have signed up to use me, so you better take these methods and define them properly".

An interface will only describe method headers, but not actually offer any content to it, it is left to the class that implements the interface.

further more, understand the following
inheritence - enables a class to inherit the attributes and methods of its parent class, but the same child class cannot inherit directly from 2 parent classes, you can however have a child class inherit from a parent class which inherits from another class which implements an interface.
here is an example

```
 public interface Entity{
    ...
    }
    public Soldier implements Entity{
    // implements the entity interface,
    //and defines the methods
    }
    public SwordsMan extends Soldiers{
    //this class inherits the methods and attributes of soldier
    //which had also implemented the methods from entity

}
```

You also mention trying to extend an interface into an interface, interfaces are designed with no implemented methods, if you want to use two interfaces you are best to do this:

```
public class Aircraft implements Engine, Entity{
//this class then has to implements all methods from Engine and Entity
}
```